# Having trouble importing packages in java

Tags: java

I'm in the process of a personal project I'm working on, and I'm trying to import packages I've created in **Java**.

Say that my directory is `C:\Users\B\Desktop\gamingResearch\pokemonGames` and in that directory I have the files `Battle.java`, `Move.java`, and another folder called `pokemon`. In my header for `Battle.java`, I have

```
import pokemonGames.trainerClass.Trainer;
import pokemonGames.pokemon.*;
```

And I try to compile the class with `javac -sourcepath .:/Desktop/gamingResearch/pokemonGames Battle.java`

But I still get an error saying

> error: package pokemonGames.pokemon does not exist.

I'm running into the same errors in other classes regarding packages that I've made. Is there something that I'm forgetting to do?

Comment: You're missing `-cp` for setting the classpath for the other packages

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd suggest using an IDE, makes life a lot easier

Comment: Use an IDE, it would be very much helpful to triage and debug issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your sourcepath is wrong.

It should be:

```
-sourcepath /Desktop/gamingResearch
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you program in java, you do need to add libraries (like pokemonGames) to your classpath before compiling your application, like already stated in the comment by cricket_007.

To make things slightly simpler, you could use a build tool like gradle or maven or even just use an IDE (like IntelliJ) to build your application. Please note, that I recommend a build tool as well as using an IDE, so that you are able to build your application on other machines with different IDEs.